# Is there a way to write data to CSV without repeating data? (Using Python)

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I am working on a webscraping project in python. I have managed to get the data in the command line, now that it is time to put it into excel/.csv, I tried using import csv and opening file in append mode. It worked but when run again, adds repetitive data. How will be the best way to avoid that and make it efficient?

Output:

```
Status,School,Details
Accepted,Notre Dame / Mendoza,GMAT: 690 Round: Round 4 | Midwest
Note,Vanderbilt / Owen,GRE: 318 Round: Round 2
Waitlisted,Dartmouth / Tuck,GMAT: 720 Round: Round 2
Waitlisted,Vanderbilt / Owen,GPA: 3.4 Round: Round 3 | Ohio
Waitlisted,Vanderbilt / Owen,GPA: 3.84 GMAT: 720 Round: Round 3 | Ohio
Accepted,Vanderbilt / Owen,"GPA: Grad:  4.00 / Undergrad:  3.57 GRE: 319 Round: Round 3 | Nashville, TN"
Rejected,UT Austin / McCombs,GPA: 3.5 Round: Round 3 | Canada
Accepted,Vanderbilt / Owen,GPA: 3.5 GRE: 315 Round: Round 3 | Mid West
Accepted,Georgia Tech / Scheller,GPA: 3.0 Round: Round 3 | NYC/Texas
Accepted,Rice / Jones,GPA: 3.4 GMAT: 700 Round: Round 3 | Texas
Accepted,Rice / Jones,"GPA: 3.27 GRE: 308 Round: Round 3 | Houston, TX"
```

Comment: I just made an edit. The data that is being printed, gets repeated. Maybe the way I have implemented the code is wrong. Or will this look better with pandas?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated"? Some entries contain similar data but they are distinct nonetheless.

Comment: @Mr.T I mean that when I run the code for page 1 and 2, and then for page 1 to 5, the same block of data from page 1 and 2 gets repeated. Is there anyway that can be solved? (I hope i was clear this time)

Comment: the file writer is in `append` mode.

Comment: @Doc Yes I am aware, will making it into Write mode do the job?

Comment: `write` mode will clear out the old stuff and write the new ones so not useful if going like pages 1,2 in first hit and then 3,4,5 later on. You'll have to start again at page 1.